# Emulator Control in Android-Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator, location

I am developing an application of getting current GPS location. For that to get current latitude and longitude.

- I opened "Emulator Control"
- Noticed a Disabled Send button

And tried a lot but it doesn't Enable. Any way to enable the Send button on the Emulator

Comment: Have you selected your emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

First of all open `Devices` and then select your `emulator` or `Devices`
. After `Send Button`  will be 
will be enabled automatically.

Comment: i m really very sorry.....i forgot to reply. i got the answer...first go to window->show view->DDMS->Device ->select any thread... then send button was enabled.... sometimes i need to "Reset the adb" to enable send button...thanks for your respone